# How to specify the initial context detail for JMS connection factory lookup

Tags: java, jboss, jms

I faced a situation at work where I need to specify the initial context name to an underlying architecture component so that it can help me post message to a JMS Queue.

How do I specify the exact context factory name?
I presume this is probably the string to be used "`org.jnp.interfaces.namingcontextfactory`" based on google results. I would like to understand what is the authoritative method to arrive at this string taking perhaps the jboss server configuration as the starting point?

Thanks
Cinish

Comment: welcome to So.. Please try include some relevant code when asking question.

Answer (score 1):

The initial context is a reference to a [JNDI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/) namespace where objects like JMS Queues can be looked up. I wrote this [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jmsvendor/) some time ago, which you might find helpful.

For a **remote** jboss server, there are 3 basic this should be (using the default port):

- **java.naming.factory.initial**: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
- **java.naming.factory.url.pkgs**: org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
- **java.naming.provider.url**: <hostname>:1099

The code would look something like this:

```
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.jms.*;
import java.util.*;
.....
Properties jndiProps = new Properties();
jndiProps.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
jndiProps.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
jndiProps.put("java.naming.provider.url", "localhost:1099");
Context ctx = new InitialContext(jndiProps);
Queue jmsQueue = (Queue)ctx.lookup("jndi-name-of-queue");
```

If your code is running *inside* the jboss server, you don't need those properties since they are implicit.

```
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.jms.*;
.....
Context ctx = new InitialContext(); // no properties needed
Queue jmsQueue = (Queue)ctx.lookup("jndi-name-of-queue");
```

Comment: Link to your tutorial leads to HTTP 404

Comment: Sorry about that. It was quite old and it got unlisted.

Comment: @Nicholas I'm following this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nGYG8sgE7E). It describes how to communicate between two clients using jms with glassfish server. The tutorial uses iiop://localhost:3700 as the provider url. However, the code is failing to connect with the reason: "Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: iiop://localhost:3700" .... "Failed to connect to server iiop:1099". Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Note: when I try use an empty constructor for the context as suggested for local server situation, I'm also receiving an error: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: "Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or in an application resource file: java.naming.factory.initial"